# Activate a Subscriber from Server Side Javascript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, subscriber

Is there a way to Activate a subscriber using Server Side Javascript or Ampscript. I am able to Unsubscribe an Active subscriber but not able to Activate an Unsubscribe subscriber in SFMC.

Is there a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your scenario, you'd use the [update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpdate.htm) SSJS function to change the status of the subscriber.

Here is an example:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
  var subscriber = {"Status": "Active"};
  var subObj = Subscriber.Init("Subscriber_Key_Here");
  var status = subObj.Update(subscriber);
</script>
```

Comment: Works, Thank you. Just wondering if there are similar methods for Opting-In and Opting-Out Mobile Connect Contacts as well. Are there any?

Comment: I believe Mobile Connect would require a REST API call, not default SSJS function.