# How We can update All Subscriber object while sending an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am trying to update the status of the User from Unsubscriber to Active at the time of sending an email, is there any way we can do while sending an email?

I tried the code on the Cloud page and it is working but I am finding a way to update while sending an email.

Comment: So you want to send an email to someone who's unsubscribed previously?  Perhaps you can update your question to clarify your use-case.

Comment: Hi @Adam Thank you! Yes, we have a trigger send and at the time of sending the email we are trying to update the status of the User in all subscribers. So we are getting an API call to send a welcome email, the purpose of updating the status is if the same user unsubscribed previously they can again subscribe at the time of  sending the welcome email

Answer (score 1):

If your subscriber has given consent to opt back in after previously being unsubscribed from marketing emails -- there's no way for a triggered send email to update the status.

You'll need to make an additional [SOAP API call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/update_a_subscriber.html) to update the status -- or if you're using a CloudPage, you can use [AMPscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102501/5202) or [SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/211567/5202) to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Adam,
I followed another approach
I am uploading a DE with the same record while sending the trigger to send DE
Then every Morning Extracting the DE data to FTP and then Import the in All SUbscriber With the active status.
All IN All, it working: thanks for your help!